# It is a good idea to use reboot.css (from Bootstrap) in a Non Bootstrap project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reset

If so, why did not they put it as an independent library/file ?

I know **reboot.css** is "opinionated" about some features like: box-size: border-box by default, rem units use, margin-top removal, System Font Family etc..

If I'm ok with those features, can I use it or is there something that can cause problems etc..

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with using reboot.css in any project where you want those features. If something doesn't behave the way you want it to when you're coding your site then be sure to look at reboot.css to see what they're making it do so you can adapt it to your needs.